# datagridcombobox 2 sql datatables

Tags: sql, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I'm building a program that loads its settings from a sql table, additionally it loads existing work orders from another sql table.

I need to populate a datagridcombobox options with the options in the "appdata" sql table and then set the selected option to whatever is saved in the other sql "tickets" table.

I can set the datasource to either of the tables but I don't see a way to load one then set the value to the other.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please give your question the appropriate, meaningful title to attract users attention

Answer (score 0):

you can make the following:

- open an `OleDbConnection` to your database.
- create an `OleDbCommand` with a command text of a query from 'appdata' table and fill the combobox items with the returned results (don't forget to close the reader).
- repeat the previous step with a command text of a query from 'tickets'' table and get the value with `ExecuteScalar` and put the returned value into the comboBox `selectedValue` (or `selectedIndex`).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to increment through all the table values. Is there no way to set the "tickets" table as the datasource and specify the column to populate the selectedvalue on all the rows after using the "appdata" table to populate the options?

Comment: There is a hack, why don't you make another hidden combobox and set tickets table as it's datasource, and then you can read the values directly from this combobox instead of changing the datasource of your actual comboxbox.